# Getting different results with two methods for a Markov Chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Given the below Markov transition matrix, calculate $p_{0,1}^9$

\begin{matrix}
        0.5 & 0.5 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}

1. Method one, take the matrix powered to the 9. Then take the 0,1 index from that matrix. Result :

   \begin{matrix}
           0.00195 & 0.666 & 0.332 \\
           0 & 0 & 1 \\
           0 & 1 & 0 \\
           \end{matrix}
2. Second method:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Transient_evolution
   Result : $0.5^8*0.5^1 = 0.00195$ (which weirdly coincides with index 0,0 of the powered matrix.

Am I overlooking something ?

Comment: I guess you are looking at the Chapman-Kolmogorov equations. You seem to have chosen $k = 8$. However, $p_{ir}^{(k)}$ should be interpreted as element $(i,r)$ from the matrix $P^k$ and is (usually) not equal to the $k$-th power of element $(i,r)$ from the matrix $P$.

Comment: Third method: $$p_{0,1}^{9}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{2^5}+\frac{1}{2^7}+\frac{1}{2^9}=\frac{2}{3}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{10}}\right)\approx0.666015625$$

Comment: Thank you both for your insight. Ritz I thought the point of the Chapman-Kolmogorov equation was to avoid calculating the 9th power of the P matrix. Turns out I was wrong.

@Did May I ask what formula or logic you used ?

Comment: Simple: enumerate the paths leading from state 0 to state 1 in 9 steps and sum their probabilities. For example the probability 1/2^3 corresponds to the path 0001212121.

Comment: That makes sense, in this example there are only 5 possible paths. Thank you both for your insight. Don't know how to mark comments as answers though !